# Passing type <T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method in third party component which can be invoked like the below code:

```
ICustomer log = Axis.GetInstance<ICustomer>();
```

Since i do not want to expose the above third party component directly to all the callers, i decided to create a wrapper method which calls the third party "Axis.GetInstance()", My problem is how to pass the type T and invoke the method inside the generic method

calling code:

```
var result = Util.MyCustomWrapper<ICustomer>();


public class Util
{
  public static T MyCustomWrapper<T>()
  {

    1.call Axis.GetInstance<T>(); // **how to pass the type T**
    2.return T

  }
}
```

Comment: `return Axis.GetInstance<T>();` "doesn't work" how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method can called just as you have written it:

```
public static T MyCustomWrapper<T>()
{
    return Axis.GetInstance<T>();
}
```

Comment: i get this error when i write like this "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use"

Comment: @TiffanyHarry then you must add a type constraint to your method: `where T : class`

Comment: @TiffanyHarry: Aha, that probably means that the generic argument for `Axis.GetInstance` defines a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) that requires the type argument to be a reference type. Define the same (or a more restrictive) constraint on your `T` argument: `MyCustomWrapper<T>() where T : class`

Comment: @TiffanyHarry This is why you should post the actual error rather then "it doesn't work"

Comment: @phoog, @ O.R Mapper: there was a type constraint..now it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Util
{
    public static T MyCustomWrapper<T>()
    {
        T customer = Axis.GetInstance<T>(); 
        return customer;
    }
}
```

Plus the other types to compile

```
public interface ICustomer { }
public class Axis
{
    public static T GetInstance<T>() 
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```